# calculus - evaluating this triple integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$\int \int \int_R y+z \space dx\space dy\space dz $ with $ R $ being the cube portion $0\le x, y,z \le1 $ under the plane $x+y+z=2 $ and above the plane $y+z=1 $

I'm really confused about boundaries here. I was wondering if splitting it like this

$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (\int_{1-z}^{2-z-x} x+y \space dy)\space dx \space dz $ is right. Probably wrong, but worth a try I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost correct! The problem with this is that $y\leq1$ but if say $x=z=0$ then the integral goes up to $2$. It should really be
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(\int_{1-z}^{\min(2-z-x,1)} x+y \space dy\right)\space dx \space dz$$
The only way i see to do this integral efficiently is to split it into two sections, one where the minimum is $1$ (i.e $x+z\le1$ and one where the minimum is greater than $1$ (i.e where $x+z>1$), like so:
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-z} \left(\int_{1-z}^{1} x+y \space dy\right)\space dx \space dz+\int_0^1\int_{1-z}^1 \left(\int_{1-z}^{2-x-z} x+y \space dy\right)\space dx \space dz$$

Comment: Thank you very much!